# Consuming Web-Service via WCF with digital certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, certificate

I am developing an application that needs to use a Web Service (WSDL). To access this WSDL I need to use a certificate.pfx. I have already installed this certificate on my computer. I've already managed to access this WS through the browser and SOAPUi. However, when I try to import the WSDL through Visual Studio (WCF / .net core), it gives the error below:

> An error occurred while attempting to find services at
> 'https://xxxxxxx-spi-homo-ws-site1.xxxx.com/wsdl'. The remote server
> returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

When I try to use WS through .NET Framework 4.7, clicking on "Project> Add Service Reference> Advanced> Add Web Reference", asks for confirmation of the certificate (Figure 1). When I click OK, it gives another error (Figure 2).

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

I tried, in the browser, to do a "Save As ..." and created a .wsdl file and made the import through the "Browse" of "Visual Studio" and gave the error below:

[image: Figure 3]

I would like to know how I make Visual Studio use the certificate to access the WSDL.

Comment: This may be a server-side problem, can you access the wsdl file in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you can open the WSDL file in your browser, you can save it locally:

[image]

Then, you can use svcutil to generate proxy classes,svcutil is a .NET tool that retrieves metadata from a web service on a network location or from a WSDL file, and generates a WCF class containing client proxy methods that access the web service operations.

You can use this tool on the command-line interface of VS:

[image]

Executing the above command will generate the a proxy class and configuration file on disk D.Then add these two files to your project.

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.